# reading a number into a char

Tags: c, char, int, scanf

what happens if I read an integer like 20,30,10000...9999 into variable **a** ? it only prints the first digit in the number that I've read...why is that ?
for example if I read **123**, on the screen it prints 1. Isn't it supposed to convert the integer **123** into it's equivalent ASCII character representation ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char a;

    scanf("%c", &a);
    printf("%c", a);

    return 0;
}
```

This is an exam question from C language.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &a);` reads a `char` from `stdin`.  When the user types "1", "2", "3" Enter, 4 `char` are given to the program: `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'\n'`.  For the keyboard, users normally only enter text, not integers.  Functions like `scanf("%c", &a);` read one `char`.  `int d; scanf("%d", &d);` will read text and convert that text into an `int`.

Comment: also be sure not to do `char ch; scanf("%d", (int*)&ch);`!!! It will write `sizeof(int)` bytes at ch location overwriting (spoiling) other variables nearby. I had a related bug once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it reads the character, which is represented by the machine as a small integer, into the variable.

If you enter <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> (the number 100, three keypresses and thus three characters), it will only store the first *character* of that, i.e. the leading `1`.

If you wanted to convert a number to an actual integer, you should use `%d` and an `int` variable of course.

Printing with `%c` will print back a single character, by interpreting the small integer value as a character (rather than as an integer). So for an input of <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> you will see `1` printed back out, i.e. the character that represents the decimal digit one.

If you want to print out the numeric representation of the character you read in, scan with `%c` but print with `%d`, and cast the `char` to `(int)` in the `printf()` call.

Comment: I'm still confused...so it reads the equivalent ASCII character which in turn is represented as a small integer that is stored in the variable ? but then when I print it out why doesn't print the char ?

Comment: If you print it with `%c`, then it will print it "the char", in your case `1` which is a rather typical character. I don't understand your confusion, right now.

Comment: oohh alright, so it reads 1 as a character like '1' not as the digit 1 so if I read 12, here are actually two characters '1' and '2' ...

Comment: Huu, this must be laaaarge keyboard with keys labled up to "*10000*" ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that %c parse a char for console input. From a number like 123 it take only the first letter and dispose the rest. The way to parse a int value is using %d on the scanf function.

Comment: I know that but let's say that I enter the value 9 then it should print \t on the screen since I use %c in printf, but instead it prints 9

Comment: The %c get the ascii code of the first char on the console input. When you write 9 on the console and parse with the %c, the asccii code of 9  is stored in the variable. After that you use printf("%c", a) and you will see the 9 again because the %c print the ascci representation of the variable value.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will read only the first character into the char variable. How can a char variable store more than one character at an instant? It can't.

So if you want the ASCII value, input as an integer instead.

```
int a;
scanf("%d", &a); // suppose input is 65
printf("%c", a); // prints 'A'
printf("%d", a); // prints 65
```

Whereas

```
char a;
scanf("%c", &a); // suppose input is 65
printf("%c", a); // prints '6'
printf("%d", a); // prints 54 which is the ASCII value of '6'
```

Comment: A `char` is an 8 bit integer, either signed or unsigend depending on the implemetation. So it can very well represent 256 different integer values.

Comment: My comment referred to this: "*How can a char variable store more than one characters?*"

Comment: I must take a language class.

Comment: To close the loop here, you could follow the line:  `printf("%c", a);` in your answer with another: printf("%d", a); to illustrate the difference a format specifier makes.

Comment: @ryyker thank you ! I figured it out just a few seconds before your post using this technique